# Setting config variable in heroku MandrilL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, config, mandrill

I am trying to change the config variable but am getting an error message.

This is what I am trying and the response:

```
$ heroku config:set MANDRILL_APIKEY=_whatAcoolHiddenKey
    Setting config vars and restarting cool-heroku-1019... failed
    !    Cannot overwrite attachment values MANDRILL_APIKEY.
```

How can I get the desired result of changing the variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit config vars on your app’s settings tab on Dashboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Mandrill Add-On enabled? If so, then Heroku will not allow you to override the API Key provided by the Add-On.

You'll want to disable the Mandrill Add-On and then set the config variable.